# Moodle apache proxy

Tags: apache, proxy, reverse, moodle

I'm having troubles setting up a moodle instance behind an apache proxy.

Here's my apache front-end that proxies to the running server.

```
NameVirtualHost www.example.com:443
<VirtualHost www.example.com:443>
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyRequests Off
  ServerName www.example.com
  ServerAlias www.example.com
  ProxyPass / http://192.168.1.101/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.1.101/
  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/crt/example.com.crt
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/crt/example.com.key
  SSLCACertificatePath /etc/ssl/crt
  SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/crt/example.com.bundle.crt
</VirtualHost>
```

On the concrete server I've got.

```
 $CFG->wwwroot = 'http://192.168.1.101/classes';
```

And

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.1.101:80>
    ServerAlias 192.168.1.101
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName 192.168.1.101
    DocumentRoot /var/www/
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
            AllowOverride None
            Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
    <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
            Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
            Order deny,allow
            Deny from all
            Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

The thing is that I keep getting that moodle is only accessible from 182.168.1.101 something is not quite matching the expected. I've been able to configure confluence and other platforms but moodle doesn't work.

The concrete error is as follows.

```
Incorrect access detected, this server may be accessed only through "http://192.168.1.101/classes"       address, sorry. Please notify server administrator.
```

Does anyone know what might be happening?

Answer (score 2):

Its a Moodle error message, the wwwroot in config.php has to match.

You could try

```
$CFG->wwwroot   = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
```

Although this might not allow some command line updates in Moodle.

Comment: hum, no I think. Apache goes from https and makes the request using http. The main problem now is that I cannot test it because I already got a workaround and since it's production environment I won't try it again, only if I really need to. Nevertheless thank you for your effort :)

Answer (score 2):

On the proxy server, modify the VirtualHost entry as follows:

```
ProxyPass / http://192.168.1.101/classes
ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.1.101/classes
```

For Moodle, what you set in Moodle's config.php for

`$CFG->wwwroot`

...has to match your `ProxyPass` and `ProxyPassReverse` values in the VirtualHost definition on the Proxy server.

Answer (score 1):

So, what's the URL that points to your front end?

That's what you need to set $CFG->wwwroot to.